# Mac + vim : character ASCII 160 instead 32 as space

Tags: key-bindings, macvim

This is a problem that is making me crazy so any help is welcomed :-)

That happens to me mainly when typing scripts with Vim in Mac but I *think* I got the problem *somethimes* when typing some commands in the shell but I am not sure.
To make the things more complicated, I can't describe a use case case when it happens... just happens :-( !

Everything starts when I try to run a bash scripts I have written using vim and then I get an error like

```
./script.sh: line 120: [[ 0: command not found
```

Next step I debug the script adding

```
set -x
```

and I see

```
+ '[[ 0' -eq 1 ']]'
./script.sh: line 120: [[ 0: command not found
```

and If I check the source code I see something like

```
if [[ $doSth -eq 1 ]]
```

so it seems that what is between '[[' and $'doSth' is **not** a space.

Ok, let's show the hidden characters using

```
:set list
```

and what I get

```
if [[ $doSth -eq 1 ]]$
```

so nothing weird. Finally what I did was to see the ASCII characters below the cursor with

```
:set laststatus=2
:set statusline=%<%f%h%m%r%=%b\ 1x%B\ \ %l,%c%V\ %P
```

and here I started to see *some light*:

- The ASCII for a **real** space is 32
- The ASCII for that character that **seems a space** is 160

The problem is *easy* to solve: I remove it and type an space again but .... what is going on?

I run:

- iTerm
- Then tmux
- Then vim

So I guess something *in the way* get wrong but I have no idea what is going on so any help will be more than welcomed :-)

Comment: Dec 160, is the non-breaking space. I have seen this error mostly from copy-pasting from e.g. word, which likes to replace characters by "more appropriate and nicer looking ones" (which unfortunately causes such issues). You can also use `ga` on such a character

Comment: On a Mac, a non-breaking space is inserted with Option-Space. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/78245/879179) for ways to disable that key mapping, not sure if one of those answers will work for you directly... You can try an `inoremap` on Vim, but I'm not sure of the exact syntax you'd need, I'm not on a Mac here so I couldn't test the exact issue you're having to test a solution within Vim itself...

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! As @filbranden notes, Option+Space inserts a non-breaking space on a Mac. With that information, I'm not convinced the questions as stands is relevant or belongs here. My recommendation would be to close it with our "typo" close reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I think I have all the info for facing with annoyance feature :-)